# jQuery "Chosen" plugin for Select dropdown - get ID

Tags: jquery, jquery-chosen

I am using the [chosen plugin](http://harvesthq.github.com/chosen/) for jQuery and love it, but I am trying to create a common script to use for all `SELECT` queries within my application that have a certain class. The problem is I am trying to get the ID for the active Chosen Select.  Below is my jQuery code.

```
$("SELECT.editable").chosen({
    create_option: function (term) {
        var chosen = this;
        chosen.append_option({
            value: term,
            text: term
        });
        var tableField = $(this).attr('id'); // <<<< HERE IS THE ISSUE. I am trying to get the ID of the select to pass to the jQuery post as a paramter. It comes back as undefined.
        alert(tableField);
        var params = { optionValue: term, tableField: tableField };
        var paramsStr = $.param(params);
        var actionUrl = '/Setup/_addDropDownOption';
        $.post(actionUrl, paramsStr);
    },
    persistent_create_option: false,
    create_option_text: 'Add Option'
});
```

Any help would be appreciated.

Here's my HTML code from View Source.

```
<div>
<select class="editable" id="tblContacts.Prefix" name="Prefix">
<option selected="selected" value="Mr.">Mr.</option>
<option value="Ms.">Ms.</option>
<option value="Mrs.">Mrs.</option>
<option value="Mr. and Mrs.">Mr. and Mrs.</option>
<option value="Miss.">Miss.</option>
<option value="Mr. and Dr.">Mr. and Dr.</option>
<option value="Dr. and Mrs.">Dr. and Mrs.</option>
<option value="Dr.">Dr.</option>
</select>
<span class="field-validation-valid" data-valmsg-for="Prefix" data-valmsg-replace="true"></span>
</div>
```

I created a [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/wxWDH), but I'm not sure if I did it right. Let me know if I need to do something different.

Comment: Can you show the relevant parts of your html please.

Comment: Or even better, set up a jsfiddle ;)

Comment: Setup a breakpoint right after "var chosen = this;"  Hover over chosen, and see how it's defined at that moment.  Also, you should just be able to use $(chosen) instead of $(this).

Comment: I set the breakpoint but VS states that "The breakpoint will not currently be hit. No symbols have been loaded for this document."

Comment: I created a jsfiddle, not sure if I did it right but here it is.

http://jsfiddle.net/wxWDH/

Let me know if I need to do something different.

Comment: Did you manage to resolve this issue? I presume you were actually using this fork of chosen: https://github.com/koenpunt/chosen as the original harvesthq one you linked to doesn't contain create_option.

Comment: may be it will work to get which select box is active

$(".chosen-select").chosen(); 
$('.chosen-select').bind('change', function(evt, params) {
                    if(params.selected != ""){
                        $(this).addClass("active")
                    }
                });

Comment: Once the class attribute of the select control is set correctly in the HTML (e.g. chosen-select), it should be as straightforward as setting var tableField = chosen.form_field.id (see a similar problem I posted and answered here: https://github.com/koenpunt/chosen/issues/56).

Answer (score 1):

First of all, the class of your select should be `chosen-select`. Like this:

```
<select class="chosen-select editable" id="tblContacts.Prefix" name="Prefix">
    <option selected value="Mr.">Mr.</option>
    <option value="Ms.">Ms.</option>
    <option value="Mrs.">Mrs.</option>
    <option value="Mr. and Mrs.">Mr. and Mrs.</option>
    <option value="Miss.">Miss.</option>
    <option value="Mr. and Dr.">Mr. and Dr.</option>
    <option value="Dr. and Mrs.">Dr. and Mrs.</option>
    <option value="Dr.">Dr.</option>
</select>
```

Also, if you wish to iterate over a set of elements, `jQuery::each` comes handy.
So the script would be:

```
// create all the chosen-selects
$(".chosen-select").chosen();

// iterate over all the .editable selects
$('select.editable').each(function() {    
    var chosen = $(this);
    var selected_option = chosen.find(':selected').val();        
    var select_id = chosen.attr('id');

    alert('The ID you are looking for is "' + select_id + '"');
    alert('The selected option is "' + selected_option + '"');

    // append element
    var option = "<option value='whatever_value'>Whatever</option>";
    chosen.append(option);
    // refresh the chosen-select
    chosen.trigger('chosen:updated');        
});
```

Here's the [**JSFiddle**](https://jsfiddle.net/espusntj/).
Make sure you include jQuery in addition of the chosen plugin.

Answer (score 0):

It should be a simple case of modifying one line of your code to get this to work. The author of the Chosen jQuery plugin you are using seems happy with the following modification, which I used when I encountered a similar issue [documented here](https://github.com/koenpunt/chosen/issues/56).

```
$("SELECT.editable").chosen({
    create_option: function (term) {
        var chosen = this;
        chosen.append_option({
            value: term,
            text: term
        });
        // *** I modified the following line ***
        var tableField = chosen.form_field.id
        // *** End of modification ***
        alert(tableField);
        var params = { optionValue: term, tableField: tableField };
        var paramsStr = $.param(params);
        var actionUrl = '/Setup/_addDropDownOption';
        $.post(actionUrl, paramsStr);
    },
    persistent_create_option: false,
    create_option_text: 'Add Option'
});
```